# How to measure performance of Web Services Security with Java and Netbeans?

Tags: java, performance, web-services, security, netbeans

I have a project about web services security and i want to do some measurements  on the different security mechanisms such as Username authentication, mutual certificates,ssl,etc. Netbeans has a list of all these mechanisms. What is the best way to measure the performance of the web services ? Is there a way to analyze what kind of processes made the web service call to take that long ?

For now all i am doing is just measuring the time difference as shown bellow. Is there a better way to do it ? more precise and correct ?

```
long time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
org.me.calculator.client.CalculatorWS port = service.getCalculatorWSPort();
int result = port.add(i,j);
long time2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
long result_time = time2-time1;
```

Comment: Did you try SoapUI? It's got very neat features for load testing and reporting.

Comment: Or http://jmeter.apache.org/? There is also a NetBeans plugin for it which allows you to profile the code while executing the jmeter testrun.